# How to find locations between two radius from a point in mongodb and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection where I am keeping all the locations with lat and long.
To find the records in 500m radius and 1000m radius is like following,

```
{
  loc: {
    $geoWithin: {
      $centerSphere: [[lng, lat], (radiusInMiles / 3963.2)]
    }
  }
}
```

But, what if I have to find all the records between the two radiuses, like records between 500m and 1000m.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
{
 loc: {
   $near: {
     $geometry: {
        type: "Point" ,
        coordinates: [ <longitude> , <latitude> ]
     },
     $maxDistance: <distance in meters>,
     $minDistance: <distance in meters>
   }
 }
}
```

[MongoDB Manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/near/)